# Auto invoke lightning component after a sucessful case creation?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have a requirement where a lightning component needs to be launched upon successful creation of case. Is it possible with lightning platform events or anyother way of auto invoking the lightning component as soon as the case is created successfully?

Comment: What does "invoke" mean here? How is the user creating the Case - though the standard UI, or custom functionality? Are you using a Lightning Utility Bar? What does the component need to do?

Comment: Yes creating case through standard UI. Upon creation of case landing on case record page. But need is to open up a custom lightning component automatically upon sucessful creation of case of a certain type.

Comment: Lightning components are not usually described as "opening up". Could you please [edit] your question to be more specific about what you are trying to do? (Open a modal, redirect the user's browser, something else...?)

Answer (score 0):

Add the lightning component to the Case detail page. If you are adding it to a tabbed panel with multiple tabs, make sure to add it to the default tab. Once the Case is created from the Standard UI, the default behavior is to land on the Case detail page which will in turn cause your Lightning Component to be invoked.